# How to debug google tag manager ios

Tags: swift, google-tag-manager

I am following [this guide](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/setup-google-tag-manager-ios-with-swift/), however, in my console log, this is what I get

```
2015-12-31 13:29:20.088 Offpeak[4391:1963569] GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 __70-[GAIBatchingDispatcher checkIAdCampaignAttributionWithHitParameters:]_block_invoke (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:749): iAd campaign tracking disabled because the iAd framework is not linked. See http://goo.gl/426NGa for instructions.
2015-12-31 13:29:20.112 Offpeak[4391:1963501] GoogleTagManager info: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002
2015-12-31 13:29:20.116 Offpeak[4391:1963501] GoogleTagManager verbose: Setting refresh time to saved time: 1451535770832
2015-12-31 13:29:20.116 Offpeak[4391:1963501] GoogleTagManager verbose: scheduleTask: containerId=GTM-NL54HS delay=39210715.295898
location <+3.08156886,+101.58254363> +/- 100.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/31/15, 1:29:20 PM Malaysia Time
2015-12-31 13:29:20.331 Offpeak[4391:1963501] GoogleTagManager info: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002
2015-12-31 13:29:21.039 Offpeak[4391:1963569] GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:195): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
2015-12-31 13:29:21.040 Offpeak[4391:1963569] GoogleTagManager verbose: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:632): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?ul=en&_v=mi3.1.4&an=Offpeak&dm=iPhone8%2C1&a=611823250&_s=10&ds=app&aid=com.offpeak.app&sr=640x1136&t=appview&tid=UA-51741047-1&cd=Home&v=1&cid=639ccb24-4dca-4def-86c2-21171a7e2bbb&_u=.4nL&av=1.2.5&_crc=0&ht=1451539760069&qt=970&z=3038422919361813367
2015-12-31 13:29:21.122 Offpeak[4391:1963501] GoogleTagManager info: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:226): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status -1
2015-12-31 13:29:21.123 Offpeak[4391:1963569] GoogleTagManager info: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:529): hit(s) Successfully deleted
2015-12-31 13:29:21.129 Offpeak[4391:1963569] GoogleTagManager info: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:237): 1 hit(s) sent
```

May I ask how do I debug to get more info on why the hit was deleted at

> 2015-12-31 13:29:21.123

?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that an appview is sent on **2015-12-31 13:29:21.040**.
Usually, the data collection in mobile apps has a dispatch duration. GTM SDK will preserve the hits and send it later.

The delete hit that you're talking about is a hit that is sent to the GA, & GTM SDK has successfully deleted hit info from local device and logged it on to console.

You may want to check this situation by sending event hit to GA if this kind of hit is again logged or not. Also, please check your GA for the data verification.

Comment: So does the HTTP status code -1 at 2015-12-31 13:29:21.122 mean anything? The reason I thought things aren't working is because, 1) I didn't get to see the hit in google analytics. 2) I don't think HTTP status code being -1 is a positive thing